# Use SQL to select all data in row where first column equals something

Tags: sql

Is it possible to use SQL to select every piece of data in a row where the first column in the row is equal to something?

Thanks

Comment: Select * From Table_Name Where First_Column_Name = Something ? IS your first column a Varchar/NVarchar or Int?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col1='Something'` ?

Comment: This is very easy to google? (- 1)

Comment: even if it's easy what' the matter? this site is open to everybody not just dorks

Comment: I have the hunch is asking "select all data  where first row or the results is equal to something". eg. you look for all the messages you received but you want to want which is the conversation you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, it's just a simple SELECT statement.

Try this:

```
SELECT * from MyTable WHERE Field1 = 'MatchThis'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.* FROM dbo.TableName T WHERE FirstColumn = @Something
```

Comment: Correct here, but be careful with "@Something".  If the OP runs this without defining @Something, it won't work.  Just depends on what he is using in his WHERE clause.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer: Yes, just the same as if there's no table `TableName` and no colum `FirstColumn`. I doubt that this will solve the problem anyway, so OP should provide more details of the problem.

Comment: It was a simple question, just wanted to make sure the bases are covered. :)

Comment: `@Something`  will not work for all DBMS. Looks like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: i don't know which rdbms use also the at-sign for variables, however, it's not MSSQL syntax only, MySQL works also:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9d83f/1/0

Comment: It's definitely not standard SQL. Apparently only MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

IF I understand it correctly, you want to retrieve data based on just simple where condition:

```
Select * From Table_Name Where First_Column_Name = Something
```

However, I highly suggest you to go through the SQL basics because asking questions like this won't get you anywhere.

**Some Basic Resources:**

**Question Specific:** http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

**General:** http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: +1 for sure.  This shouldn't really be asked, no level of effort to find the answer.